# how to avoid space in filename?

Tags: bash

I have a bunch of files which need to be converted from `.mp4` to `.mpeg.one`. A friend of mine had suggested me this simple script. However it doesn't work because filenames contain blank spaces.

Here is the script:

```
for f in $(ls *.mp4); do ffmpeg -i "$f".mp4 "$f".mprg; done
```

Comment: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need to use `ls` in this case. As a general rule, always try to use shell builtins and glob features instead of relying on external programs (e.g. `ls`) that can introduce problems with ugly workarounds.

Also, you shouldn't 'manually' append the extension to the input file name (the one you give to `-i`) and you should strip the extension on the output file.

So the command should be:

```
for f in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$f" "${f%.mp4}".mprg; done
```

Comment: Note that `ffmpeg` chooses the output container format depending on the extension. If you want another extension, you have to specify the container format - in this case with `-f mpeg`.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `ls`, you can use `find -print0` and `xargs -0`:

```
find -name '*.mp4' -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 ffmpeg -i '{}' '{}'.mpeg
```

Followed by a rename afterwards:

```
rename s/mp4.mpeg$/mpeg/ *.mp4.mpeg
```

Answer (score 2):

- No `ls` needed
- You probably mean `.mpeg` as extension
- If you place the `"` right, spaces won't be aproblem
- `ffmpeg -i "$f".mp4` in your command will look for e.g. files.mp4.mp4, which you probably didn't mean
- Be aware that your output files will be named e.g. files.mp4.mpeg

**Possible solution:**

```
for f in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$f" "$f".mpeg; done
```